# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()||| Ktrain| BERT

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, nlp, ktrain

need your support...I am following one tutorial and trying to run on my dataset. I am getting below error ...Pls consider me a beginner so I would appreciate if you can let me know how to fix and what is the reason?

```
(x_train_bert, y_train_bert), (x_val_bert, y_val_bert), preproc = text.texts_from_array(
    x_train=x_train, y_train=y_train,
    x_test=x_val, y_test=y_val,
    class_names=train_labels.unique(),
    preprocess_mode='bert',
    lang='en',
    maxlen=65,
    max_features=35000
)
```

Error : ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Screenshot of error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q80Ve.png)

I found out that I need to use (np.allclose) I am not sure where to use in my code.....Thanks

Update: New Error after updating the code with the solution provided.
[New Error after updating code with the solution provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaAqL.png)

Comment: Try passing `train_labels.unique().tolist()` for `class_names` instead of `train_labels.unique()`.

Comment: Hi Mario Ishac... Thanks... updated code with the solution provided but got new error....updated my post and attached screenshot ....for your reference

Answer (score 0):

**Cause of first error**:  As Mario indicated, you're passing a NumPy array instead of a Python list - change to: `train_labels.unique().tolist()`

**Cause of second error**: `y_train` and `y_test` must be either NumPy arrays or lists.  It looks like you're passing an **empty** Pandas Series (`KeyError: 0`).  Don't forget `.values` when setting `y_train` and `y_test`. Alternatively, you can use `texts_from_df` and specify columns in DataFrame.